# Vertical tiny carousel autoplay horizontally

Tags: jquery, plugins, carousel

I'm using [tiny carousel](http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/) for my current school project. everything is working fine except for the autoplay.

Here is the code for autoplay and animation config:

```
$("#upcoming").tinycarousel({ interval: true });
var upcoming = $("#upcoming").data("plugin_tinycarousel");

upcoming.start();
//for carousel
$("#upcoming").tinycarousel({
      axis   : "y",
      animationTime: 500,
      infinite: true
});
```

When I included

```
$("#upcoming").tinycarousel({ interval: true });
var upcoming = $("#upcoming").data("plugin_tinycarousel");

upcoming.start();
```

My carousel that animates vertically is now horizontal. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the plugin's setting `axis` is `x` = horizontal. You need to set it to `y`.

```
$("#upcoming").tinycarousel({ interval: true, axis: 'y' });
var upcoming = $("#upcoming").data("plugin_tinycarousel");

upcoming.start();
```

Comment: Yes you are right :D

haha I failed to notice that the first time. After I posted this question I realized the plugin I downloaded already has the default setting and my overwrite is not working since I called 

    .data("plugin_tinycarousel");

:D dumb me. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes it did and thank you. I cannot upvote yet since I'm lacking points but thanks a lot :D